# If f is Lipschitz with constant K, then $|f(E)|_e \leq K |E|_e$ for EVERY subset E of the domain

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lipschitz-functions

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function with constant K, i.e., for any x, y in A, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq K|x - y|$. Prove that for *any* $E \subseteq A,$ $|f(E)|_e \leq K|E|_e$.

I can directly use the fact that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq K|x - y|$ to show the inequality holds when E is an interval, and use the interval case to show that this is true for open sets as well, but it's not clear where to go from there. I know that for any $\epsilon > 0,$ any set E can be covered by countably many closed intervals $Q_j$ so that $|E|_e \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j| \leq |E|_e + \epsilon$, and that an open set within $\epsilon$ of E's exterior measure exists as well, but the problem is that these approximate from outside of E and possibly outside of A, and I can't work out the right way to "extend" f out to the intervals or open sets and be sure that the result is still a Lipschitz function. I think it would be best if I could show the result holds for closed sets and work upward instead, but I'm not quite sure how to do that, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice statment of what you've tried. It looks to me like $f$ can be extended to all of $\mathbb {R}$ with the same Lipschitz constant. First, extend $f$ to $\bar {A};$ the extension is the same as for any uniformly continuous function on $A.$ Then $\mathbb {R}\setminus \bar {A}$ is open, hence is the pairwise disjoint union of open intervals $I_1, I_2, \dots.$ On any $I_n = (a_n,b_n),$ just connect $(a_n,f(a_n)),(b_n,f(b_n))$ with a line segment. There's the desired extension, and it would seem you're good to go. (I'm not sure why $A$ needs to be measurable though. Where does that come in?)

Comment: In the context of the class/text this is from, a "measurable function" is generally assumed to have a measurable set as its source, and Lipschitz functions are considered a subset of measurable ones; it's less a requirement for this problem than just part of the for-sanity's-sake definitions. But I'm not actually familiar with what the "standard" extension of a uniformly continuous function to the closure of its source set is, and it's not in my text, so I probably have to show it works from scratch as well as actually define the line-segment parts (though that doesn't seem too hard).

Comment: Main idea for the first extension: If $x_n$ is a sequence in $A$ and $x_n\to x,$ then $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy, hence converges. Check that the limit obtained is independent of the sequence. This gives the extension,  and the Lipschitz constant on $\bar {A}$ comes along effortlessly.

Comment: Is it really true that for every n both a_n and b_n must be in the closure of A? It seems like this doesn't make any sense, for example if A = [a, b] is just an already-closed interval then at least some of those finite I_n's must be "far away" from it (e.g. a_n - b > 0 for some n)..and if I'm right about that I'd have to somehow order the intervals so that the ones "closest" to A come first so that the definition can be done inductively, but I'm not sure conceptually how to do that, either.

Comment: Suppose only one of the $I_n$'s is infinite, say it's $(1,\infty).$ Then do what I outlined above to get an extension to $(-\infty,1].$ Is there any problem then extending it to $\mathbb {R}$?